# React serve build .js files under custom path with webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, webpack, server-side-rendering

I have a SSR react app uses express. In webpack client configuration file, i specify the output folder as

```
output: {
  filename: "[name].[contenthash].js",
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../../build/public"),
}
```

in express, i specify the public folder as:

```
app.use(Express.static("build/public"));
```

so, when i build the app, i see something like that when including to HTML document:

```
<script src="/foobar.js"></script>
```

If i change the output folder as `build/assets` or `build/public/assets` it doesn't change the files locations. It only changes the `/build` folder structure as i specified, but it keeps root folder in HTML document. I want to serve .js files under a custom path, so it would be like this:

```
<script src="/assets/foobar.js"></script>
```